# Parsing dtd file with lxml library (python)

Tags: python, lxml, dtd, dtd-parsing, xml

I need your help.
I use lxml library to parsing dtd file.

How can i get c subexpression in this example?

```
dtd = etree.DTD(StringIO('<!ELEMENT a (b,c,d)>'))
```

I try this

```
content = dtd.elements()[0].content

left, right = content.left, content.right
```

but it left of right subexpression.

http://lxml.de/validation.html#id1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm completely guessing (I've never touched this before) but:

```
from io import StringIO
from lxml import etree

dtd.elements()[0].content.right.left
#>>> <lxml.etree._DTDElementContentDecl object name='c' type='element' occur='once' at 0x7f6999a28250>
```

?

Comment: thanks, it really works.I have one more question: how can I calculate the number of elements?

Comment: Loop over the `content` variable as a tree, counting how many end-points you encounter.

Comment: I'm asking about calculate the numer of subexpression. (b,c,d) -> 3

Comment: I know. Are you going to try and use my suggestion?